# How do I set the first player in the game to be king and no one else? (ROBLOX)

Tags: lua, roblox

So I have a local king variable and I wanna set the player to it. But how do I detect the first player to join and prevent other people from being king? And if the player leaves how do I get the second person who joined to become king?

I wrote this:

local king

while wait(1) do
for i = 1, #game.Players:GetPlayers(), 1 do
if (game.Players:GetPlayers()[i].leaderstats.isKing.Value == "Yes") then return end
end

```
for i, v in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
    if (v.leaderstats.isKing.Value == "") then
        v.leaderstats.isKing.Value = "Yes"
    end
end
```

end

But clearly this will make everyone become king

So I wrote this

```
local king
    
    while wait(1) do
        for i = 1, #game.Players:GetPlayers(), 1 do
            if (game.Players:GetPlayers()[i].leaderstats.isKing.Value == "Yes") then return end
        end
        
        for i, v in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
            if (v.leaderstats.isKing.Value == "") then
                v.leaderstats.isKing.Value = "Yes"
            end
        end
    end
```

But it makes player 1 AND 2 become king, but not player 3. It should only be player 1

So I put the for loop after the king set loop and it fixed that, but how do I make it so when the king leaves the second player will become king?

Comment: Maybe you can adapt the script from the roblox forum to [get the Owner’s UserId](https://devforum.roblox.com/t/how-to-detect-game-owner/308169) and mark it with an [attribute](https://create.roblox.com/docs/studio/instance-attributes).

Answer (score 0):

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Wait()
wait()game.Players:players()[1].leaderstats.isKing.Value="Yes"
game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function()
game.Players:players()[1].leaderstats.isKing.Value="Yes"
end)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**